# Split String Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, database, substring, teradata

I'm looking to split a string in Teradata.

The table might look something like this.

```
column1
hello:goodbye:afternoon
```

I'm trying to use SUBSTRING and INSTR to extract specific words.  So, say I want to select "goodbye". I'm trying the following query.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(a.column1 from index(a.column1,':')+1 for INSTR(a.column1,':',0,2))
FROM db.table as a
```

I get the following error.

```
SELECT Failed. [3707] Syntax error, expected something like ')' between the word 'INSTR' and '('
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that error.  It lets me use INDEX to deduce a number in place of INSTR, so I'm not sure why it is acting this way when I use INSTR.

Comment: Which version of Teradata are you on? I guess it was introduced only in TD 14 and if you are on an older version, then you need to get the UDF for the same...

Comment: Looks like I'm on 13.. How do I go about this operation then?

Comment: If you can get the INSTR UDF installed, that's the easiest option. Otherwise, you may have to tinker with POSITION...you can get the UDF's from here - https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions

Answer (score 15):

If this was TD14 you wouldn't need `INSTR`, there's a `STRTOK` function :-)

```
STRTOK(column1,':',2),
```

For earlier releases it's

```
CASE 
   WHEN column1 LIKE '%:%:%'
   THEN SUBSTRING(column1 FROM POSITION(':' IN column1) + 1 FOR POSITION(':' IN 
        SUBSTRING(column1 FROM POSITION(':' IN column1) + 1)) - 1)
   WHEN column1 LIKE '%:%'
   THEN SUBSTRING(column1 FROM POSITION(':' IN column1) + 1)
END
```

The `CASE LIKE` ist just to prevent an "*string subscript out of bound*" error when there no colon.

Comment: STRTOK only works with single delimiter. what if delimiter consists of two characters(e.g. "->") dash and greater than?